# GitHub - merging changes to a branch in different folder from master

Tags: git, branch

I have been using github for quite a while. Now I have multiple branches for a project and also working on a couple of branches at the same time. For every branch I have a folder dedicated to itself and I commit and do a push to respective branches. Now I have a situation where I have to update one of my branches with changes in the master, since I branched before making the changes to the master. Before I do any commit, I created a 'playground' repo and was playing with it. This is the method I follow to merge the changes from my master to the branch and I would like to get all of your opinions on this method - whether it's correct or not and also whether something else has to be done. Of course, I figured out this method using SO, but the answers were in bits and pieces across multiple questions. But just wanted a single point where I could verify what I am doing!

As a side note, while I was looking up for information, I saw that I don't have to create separate folders for the branches and can just use 1 folder. But I like this approach better - maintaining separate folders.

Here is what I do:

```
# make some changes to master and commit it

git add .
git commit -m 'at last!'
git push -u origin master

# cd to the branch

git pull

git merge origin/master

# now commit to branch

git add .

git commit -m 'updates from master'

git push -u origin playground-0.1
```

Can you please let me know whether I am following the correct approach? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to make sure -- are you at any time using the `git branch` command when working with branches (creating, switching to a branch)? If so - when? If no - any special reason?

Comment: What I do is, use the web interface to create the branch and then clone the branch to a different sub-directory in my machine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple folders are perfectly fine, especially if you need to work *at the same time* in different branches.

Your merge (`git pull`) seems correct.
The other approach would be to rebase: see "[git merge vs. git rebase](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2013/02/merge-vs-rebase/)", in order to avoid a [messy history](http://www.derekgourlay.com/archives/428) like:

[image: merges]

But that works best if:

- you didn't already pushed your branch.
- you rebase on top of `origin/sameBranch` (ie you rebase your work on top of the same branch which received contribution from other user: that is different from rebasing one's work on top of `master`).

For different branches (like `master` and your branch), a merge is preferable, as explained in "[Why you shouldn’t use `git merge --rebase`](https://blog.glyphobet.net/essay/2504)".

[image: merge]

If `master` introduces some bugs, you know exactly where to look.

Comment: +5-Thanks! Good to know that what I am doing is not wrong. Initially I was trying rebase but nothing seemed to be happening. Guess probably it was because I didn't do a pull. Also I did push some commits to my branch (not the playground), so guess I should not rebase. And thanks for the link!